# JQgrid shows extra horizontal scroll bar in the browser even if autowidth set to true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jqgrid is showing an annoying horizontal scrollbar in the browser. I understand that it is because of vertical scroll bar width, but setting scrollOffset value to 18 or above did n't fix the issue. Any help please?

Comment: Could some one please help me in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue, here is the solution that even works when you have column chooser for jqgrid and it fixes the grid width issues correctly...

```
loadComplete: function(data) {
   fixGridWidth($("#grid"));
}

function fixGridWidth(grid) {
    grid.setGridWidth($(window).width());
}
```